# Botão Click chamar métodos diferentes

Tags: c#, winforms, método

Tenho um botão que chama o evento click *btn_Salvar* em meu form.

Como faço para este evento click chamar métodos diferentes de acordo com quem criou o form em que o botão esta contido?

**EDIT:**

Explicando melhor: Tenho o Form "frmPrincipal", este "frmPrincipal" contem dois menus, "produtorRuralToolStripMenuItem" e "pessoaFisicaToolStripMenuItem". Os dois chamam o mesmo Form, mas com alguns controles desabilitados. Este *btn_Salvar* tem que executar um metodo dependendo do itemMenu que o chamou.

Acredito que com IF ELSE eu resolveria o problema, porem quero evitar o maximo possivel o uso de IF ELSE.

Estou desenvolvendo este aplicativo em camadas: AcessoDados, GUI, Negocios, ObjetoTransferencia. Seria correto eu criar uma classe dentro da camada GUI para resolver este problema?

Segue código:

```
private void pessoaFisicaToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form frmCadPessoaFisica = new frmCadastroPessoas(new tipoFormPessoaFisica());
        frmCadPessoaFisica.MdiParent = this;
        frmCadPessoaFisica.Show();
    } 

    private void produtorRuralToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form frmCadPessoaProd = new frmCadastroPessoas(new tipoPessoaFormProdutor());
        frmCadPessoaProd.MdiParent = this;
        frmCadPessoaProd.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor o que tenta fazer com exemplos de código?

Comment: *de acordo com quem criou o form* - não seria **você** que criou o form? Pode dar mais detalhes sobre a sua situação?

Comment: Fiz um edit explicando melhor, obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assim.

```
private void MyMethod(Form frm, MenuItem itemMenu)
{
    Form frmCadPessoaFisica = new frmCadastroPessoas(frm, itemMenu);
    frmCadPessoaFisica.MdiParent = this;
    frmCadPessoaFisica.Show();
}

private void pessoaFisicaToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyMethod(new tipoFormPessoaFisica(), (MenuItem)sender);
} 

private void produtorRuralToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyMethod(new tipoPessoaFormProdutor(), (MenuItem)sender);
}
```

Dentro do seu form pode fazer

```
// Ctor é o seu construtor e frm o seu parametro que passa por exemplo tipoFormPessoaFisica
// itemMenu é seu MenuItem (estou sem compilador por isso veja qual o tipo do objecto)

ctor(Form frm, MenuItem itemMenu) {
    // Aqui pode fazer o que quiser com o itemMenu como por exemplo itemMenu.Name ou itemMenu.Text
}
```

Comment: pho3nix, após o novo form ser carregado, como saber dentro do novo form qual foi o metodo que o instanciou?

Comment: Resolvido. Obrigado.